# Python Zelle graphics - image error

Tags: python, image, error-handling, zelle-graphics

Using a mac, I am trying to set the background of my program to an image that i downloaded, I called the image "ChristmasBackground.jpg" and saved it to my documents. Using Zelle graphics, this is what I wrote:

```
XmasBack = Image(Point(600,100),"ChristmasBackground.jpg")
XmasBack.draw(win)
```

but the program is giving me an error saying:

```
couldn't open "ChristmasBackground.jpg": no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put it in the same folder of your script or write the file path

Comment: Still gives me the same error when i put it in the python application folder.

Comment: is it PIL library? @MostafaMohsen

Comment: how can i access the PIL?